# Accelerometer axis inputs driving three RGB LED strips - Trinket Pro 5V

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread, accelerometer, rgb-led, neopixel

I am looking to take the analogRead Value of the x, y and z axis (at pins 0, 2 and 4) and if it's a motion state, perform a rainbow, cylone and cascade LED sequences using Adafruit Neopixel library.

Using serial connection, I saw that x,y,z axis are read at values of approximately 300.

When I run the code it executed the three Neopixel sequences (redPin at pin 3, GreenPin at pin 5 and BluePin at pin 6) and then continues, even if there is no change of the accelerometer position.

What am I doing wrong?
I am using Arduino Trinket Pro 5V and working with the x-axis and RGB strip at pin 3 only to start.

Thank you for your help.

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include "WS2812_Definitions.h"

#define PIN1 3
#define LED_COUNT1 5
#define PIN2 5
#define LED_COUNT2 5
#define PIN3 6
#define LED_COUNT3 5

// Create an instance of the Adafruit_NeoPixel class called "leds".
// That'll be what we refer to from here on...
Adafruit_NeoPixel RedPin = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT1, PIN1, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
Adafruit_NeoPixel GreenPin = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT2, PIN2, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
Adafruit_NeoPixel BluePin = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT3, PIN3, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

const int sensorPinRed = A0;
const int sensorPinGreen = A2;
const int sensorPinBlue = A4;

int analogValue = 0;

void setup()
{

  RedPin.begin();  // Call this to start up the LED strip.
  //GreenPin.begin();
  //BluePin.begin();
  clearLEDs();   // This function, defined below, turns all LEDs off...
  RedPin.show();   // ...but the LEDs don't actually update until you call this.
  //GreenPin.show();
  //BluePin.show()}

void loop()
{
  do{
   analogValue = analogRead(sensorPinRed);
  // Ride the Rainbow Road
  for (int i=0; i<LED_COUNT1*10; i++)
  {
    rainbow(i);
    delay(100);  // Delay between rainbow slides
  }

  // Indigo cylon
  // Do a cylon (larson scanner) cycle 10 times
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    // cylon function: first param is color, second is time (in ms) between cycles
    cylon(INDIGO, 500);  // Indigo cylon eye!
  }

  // A light shower of spring green rain
  // This will run the cascade from top->bottom 20 times
  for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
  {
    // First parameter is the color, second is direction, third is ms between falls
    cascade(MEDIUMSPRINGGREEN, TOP_DOWN, 100); 
  }
  } while (analogValue>300);
}

// Implements a little larson "cylon" sanner.
// This'll run one full cycle, down one way and back the other
void cylon(unsigned long color, byte wait)
{
  // weight determines how much lighter the outer "eye" colors are
  const byte weight = 4;  
  // It'll be easier to decrement each of these colors individually
  // so we'll split them out of the 24-bit color value
  byte red = (color & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
  byte green = (color & 0x00FF00) >> 8;
  byte blue = (color & 0x0000FF);

  // Start at closest LED, and move to the outside
  for (int i=0; i<=LED_COUNT1-1; i++)
  {
    clearLEDs();
    RedPin.setPixelColor(i, red, green, blue);  // Set the bright middle eye
    // Now set two eyes to each side to get progressively dimmer
    for (int j=1; j<3; j++)
    {
      if (i-j >= 0)
        RedPin.setPixelColor(i-j, red/(weight*j), green/(weight*j), blue/(weight*j));
      if (i-j <= LED_COUNT1)
        RedPin.setPixelColor(i+j, red/(weight*j), green/(weight*j), blue/(weight*j));
    }
    RedPin.show();  // Turn the LEDs on
    delay(wait);  // Delay for visibility
  }

  // Now we go back to where we came. Do the same thing.
  for (int i=LED_COUNT1-2; i>=1; i--)
  {
    clearLEDs();
    RedPin.setPixelColor(i, red, green, blue);
    for (int j=1; j<3; j++)
    {
      if (i-j >= 0)
        RedPin.setPixelColor(i-j, red/(weight*j), green/(weight*j), blue/(weight*j));
      if (i-j <= LED_COUNT1)
        RedPin.setPixelColor(i+j, red/(weight*j), green/(weight*j), blue/(weight*j));
      }

    RedPin.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

// Cascades a single direction. One time.
void cascade(unsigned long color, byte direction, byte wait)
{
  if (direction == TOP_DOWN)
  {
    for (int i=0; i<LED_COUNT1; i++)
    {
      clearLEDs();  // Turn off all LEDs
      RedPin.setPixelColor(i, color);  // Set just this one
      RedPin.show();
      delay(wait);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    for (int i=LED_COUNT1-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
      clearLEDs();
      RedPin.setPixelColor(i, color);
      RedPin.show();
      delay(wait);
    }
  }
}

// Sets all LEDs to off, but DOES NOT update the display;
// call leds.show() to actually turn them off after this.
void clearLEDs()
{
  for (int i=0; i<LED_COUNT1; i++)
  {
    RedPin.setPixelColor(i, 0);
  }
}

// Prints a rainbow on the ENTIRE LED strip.
//  The rainbow begins at a specified position. 
// ROY G BIV!
void rainbow(byte startPosition) 
{
  // Need to scale our rainbow. We want a variety of colors, even if there
  // are just 10 or so pixels.
  int rainbowScale = 192 / LED_COUNT1;

  // Next we setup each pixel with the right color
  for (int i=0; i<LED_COUNT1; i++)
  {
    // There are 192 total colors we can get out of the rainbowOrder function.
    // It'll return a color between red->orange->green->...->violet for 0-191.
    RedPin.setPixelColor(i, rainbowOrder((rainbowScale * (i + startPosition)) % 192));
  }
  // Finally, actually turn the LEDs on:
  RedPin.show();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `analogValue` in your loop to verify that it is behaving the way you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are coding to always display something on the LEDs:

```C++
  void loop()
  {
    do {
      analogValue = analogRead(sensorPinRed);
      // display stuff
    } while (analogValue > 300);
  }
```

Assuming that you want the LEDs off when `analogValue` is <= 300, you have the test in the wrong place. That always does the loop at least once. How about:

```C++
  void loop()
    {
    analogValue = analogRead(sensorPinRed);
    if (analogValue > 300) 
      {
      // display stuff
      }
    else
      {
      clearLEDs();   // Turn all LEDs off...
      RedPin.show(); 
      BluePin.show(); 
      GreenPin.show(); 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @nick-gammon for debugging my code.

I cleaned it up so below is the working sample. X-axis of the accelerometer is related to PWM pin 3 RGB LED strip, Y axis of pin 5 and Z axis to pin 6.

The LED sequence cascades once in spring green color in response to the tilt in direction.

```C++
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include "WS2812_Definitions.h"

#define PIN1 3
#define LED_COUNT1 5
#define PIN2 5
#define LED_COUNT2 5
#define PIN3 6
#define LED_COUNT3 5

// Create an instance of the Adafruit_NeoPixel class called "XPin", "YPin" and "ZPin".
// That'll be what we refer to from here on...
Adafruit_NeoPixel XPin = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT1, PIN1, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
Adafruit_NeoPixel YPin = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT2, PIN2, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
Adafruit_NeoPixel ZPin = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT3, PIN3, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

const int sensorPinX = A0;
const int sensorPinY = A2;
const int sensorPinZ = A4;

int analogValueX = 0;
int analogValueY = 0;
int analogValueZ = 0;

void setup()
{

  XPin.begin();  // Call this to start up the LED strip.
  YPin.begin();
  ZPin.begin();
  clearLEDs();   // This function, defined below, turns all LEDs off...

}

void loop()
{
   analogValueX = analogRead(sensorPinX);
   analogValueY = analogRead(sensorPinY);
   analogValueZ = analogRead(sensorPinZ);
   if ((analogValueX > 400) || (analogValueY > 400) || (analogValueZ > 400) )
   {

  // A light shower of spring green rain
  // This will run the cascade from top->bottom i times
  for (int i=0; i<1; i++)
  {
    // First parameter is the color, second is direction, third is ms between falls
    cascade(MEDIUMSPRINGGREEN, TOP_DOWN, 100); 
  }
   }
   else
   {
     clearLEDs(); // Turn all LEDs off
   }
}

// Cascades a single direction. One time.
void cascade(unsigned long color, byte direction, byte wait)
{
  if (direction == TOP_DOWN)
  {
    for (int i=0; i<LED_COUNT1; i++)
    {
      clearLEDs();  // Turn off all LEDs
      XPin.setPixelColor(i, color);  // Set just this one
      XPin.show();
      delay(wait);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<LED_COUNT2; i++)
    {
      clearLEDs();  // Turn off all LEDs
      YPin.setPixelColor(i, color);  // Set just this one
      YPin.show();
      delay(wait);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<LED_COUNT3; i++)
    {
      clearLEDs();  // Turn off all LEDs
      ZPin.setPixelColor(i, color);  // Set just this one
      ZPin.show();
      delay(wait);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    for (int i=LED_COUNT1-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
      clearLEDs();
      XPin.setPixelColor(i, color);
      XPin.show();
      delay(wait);
    }

    for (int i=LED_COUNT2-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
      clearLEDs();
      YPin.setPixelColor(i, color);
      YPin.show();
      delay(wait);
    }

    for (int i=LED_COUNT3-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
      clearLEDs();
      ZPin.setPixelColor(i, color);
      ZPin.show();
      delay(wait);
    }
  }
}

// Sets all LEDs to off, but DOES NOT update the display;
// call leds.show() to actually turn them off after this.
void clearLEDs()
{
  for (int i=0; i<LED_COUNT1; i++)
  {
    XPin.setPixelColor(i, 0);
  }
  for (int i=0; i<LED_COUNT2; i++)
  {
    YPin.setPixelColor(i, 0);
  }
  for (int i=0; i<LED_COUNT3; i++)
  {
    ZPin.setPixelColor(i, 0);
  }
}
```